# How to add a css class to sidebar first render

Tags: 7, theming

I am new to drupal theme development . I am customizing a sub theme of `zen` and wants to change the background of `sidebar-first`. So I want to know where this `sidebar_first` render array is defined and how can I add the CSS class to whole `sidebar-first` also to the nodes within the `sidebar_first` render array ?

I tried within my templates `template.php` :

```
function zensub_page_alter(&$page) {
 $page['sidebar_first'] = array(
 '#attributes' => array('class' => 'page-columns')
 );
}
```

But this causes the `sidebar-first` remove !

Comment: you can use drupal_add_css() Check the link for the function : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a template file with name `region--sidebar-first.tpl.php` in side the your theme template folder. Copy below code to inside the newly created template file

```
<?php if ($content): ?>
     <div class="my_class <?php print $classes; ?>">
       <?php print $content; ?>
     </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

replace my_class with you desire class name, clear the drupal cache. It will wrap a new class on the sidebar first region. Good luck

Comment: Thanks Madhurjya...one more question, can you tell me where the render array `sidebar_first` is defined ? I searched everywhere but can't find the array !